# Training stuck on simple Pytorch model on a custom dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to train a simple Pytorch model on a procedural Dataset that I created but training seems to get stuck after the first epoch.

the dataset seems fine, it is normalized, shuffled, and if I run a batch trough my untrained model it gives me an output, but something seems to be wrong during training.

[image]

My notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qOUShw4lCehJLWOZpa4wmJhl3p_MY00Z?usp=sharing

The pytorch guide I took most of the code from:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/omarsar/pytorch_notebooks/blob/master/pytorch_quick_start.ipynb

how I'm creating my batches:

```
import math

def makebatches(x_train,y_train,batchsize):
  numBatches = math.ceil(len(x_train)/batchsize)
  batches = []
  for i in range(numBatches):
    batches.append((x_train[i*batchsize:(i+1)*batchsize],y_train[i*batchsize:(i+1)*batchsize]))
  return batches
```

training code:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
batches = makebatches(images,labels,BATCH_SIZE)
learning_rate = 0.01
num_epochs = 10

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = MyModel()
model = model.to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer =  torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)  

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_running_loss = 0.0
    train_acc = 0.0

    model = model.train()

    ## training step
    for i, (X, Y) in enumerate(batches):
        
        X = X.to(device)
        Y = Y.to(device)

        ## forward + backprop + loss
        logits = model(X)
        loss = criterion(logits, Y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        ## update model params
        optimizer.step()

        train_running_loss += loss.detach().item()
        train_acc += get_accuracy(logits, Y, BATCH_SIZE)
        #print(i)
    
    model.eval()
    print('Epoch: %d | Loss: %.4f | Train Accuracy: %.2f' \
          %(epoch, train_running_loss / i, train_acc/i))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Epoch: 0 | Loss: 0.8300 | Train Accuracy: 53.26
Epoch: 1 | Loss: 0.8445 | Train Accuracy: 52.34
Epoch: 2 | Loss: 0.8445 | Train Accuracy: 52.34
Epoch: 3 | Loss: 0.8445 | Train Accuracy: 52.34
Epoch: 4 | Loss: 0.8445 | Train Accuracy: 52.34
Epoch: 5 | Loss: 0.8445 | Train Accuracy: 52.34
Epoch: 6 | Loss: 0.8445 | Train Accuracy: 52.34
Epoch: 7 | Loss: 0.8445 | Train Accuracy: 52.34
Epoch: 8 | Loss: 0.8445 | Train Accuracy: 52.34
Epoch: 9 | Loss: 0.8445 | Train Accuracy: 52.34
```

Comment: What data are you training on and which model are you using? A first step would be to see if you can overfit your data by limiting the number of instances.

Comment: the data is images of "X" a and "O"  28x28 procedurally generated, I just tried overfitting with two images, it doesn't overfit, it gets struct with | Loss: 1.6265 | Train Accuracy: 6.25

Comment: There's your problem then. What is the model supposed to predict? How did you normalize your data?

Comment: it predicts if the image is a "X" or a "O" , I generate the images using OpenCV and normalize them dividing by 255, the images them selves seem fine, maybe the problem is how Im batching them? I'll poke at it to see if i can make it overfit